# Re Legacy code : format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]

Tags: c, unix, gcc, printf, undefined-behavior

I often try to build a lot of old simulator and disk and tape archive tools, with recent GCC. Some errors are easy to fix, but I'm not so good a programmer.

I get :

> itstar.c: In function ‘addfiles’:
>   itstar.c:194:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
>   itstar.c:194:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]

from this code fragment :

```
/* add files to a DUMP tape */
/* output buffer must have been initialized with resetbuf() */
static void addfiles(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int c=argc;
    char **v=argv;

    while(c--) {
        addfile(argc,argv,*v++);
    }
    if(verify)
        printf("Approximately %d.%d' of tape used\n",count/bpi/12,
            (count*10/bpi/12)%10);
}
```

Where line 194 is the third from last, beginning with printf.

The file is itstar.c, from tapetools, code [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/tapetools/code/HEAD/tree/itstar/itstar.c).

It builds despite the warning, but I prefer to know how to prevent it,
so the result is more efficient and there is less chance of data corruption.

Please, what have I missed, and need to change ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Now I really don't understand this.  
I ran make again, and it built without errors.

Comment: What platform is it coming from? Checking printf arguments is a recent addition to compilers, and `int` and `long` are of the same size on many platforms, notably on Win32.

Comment: I need to look up the original platform it was written on.  
I'm building on Ubuntu 13.04.  
  
Thank you for responding so fast.

Comment: @Kuze: Make probably didn't recompile the file the second time.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev  
GCC version is 4.7.3.  
Code was written in 1993, updated in 1998,  
modified by it's current packager in 2006.

Comment: @tommyo I deleted the previous target before trying again.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev that is possible but it is still undefined behavior.

Comment: @Kuze The relevant object file too?

Comment: @tommyo No, errors return after removing that.  
Thank you. Overtired.

Comment: Sorry, can't format reply to post result. Thank you, everyone. It builds now, but different warning from the next file.  Hands are shaking from tiredness.

Comment: @Kuze in general you should ask a new question.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Yes, I think this also. Better I sleep first.  
Thank you again, everyone, also for the explanation.

Answer (score 11):

Use format specifier `%lu` instead of `%d` and your compiler should stop complaining.

```
printf("Approximately %lu.%lu' of tape used\n", count/bpi/12, (count*10/bpi/12)%10);
```

Answer (score 8):

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means anything can happen including appearing to work correctly and then break later on down the road.

Looking at the source we can see both `count` and `bpi` are *unsigned long*:

```
extern unsigned long bpi; /* tape density in bits per inch */
extern unsigned long count; /* count of tape frames written */
```

the correct format specifier for these would be `%lu`.

The first argument to [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) specifies a string to print out which can contain conversion specifiers beginning with `%` that usually specifies the types of the subsequent arguments, so in your example:

```
"Approximately %d.%d' of tape used\n"
               ^^ ^^
               1  2
```

both conversion specifiers `1` and `2` are `%d` which means that `printf` will expect the next two arguments to be of type `int` but they are really of type `unsigned long`.

If we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* which also covers [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for format specifiers, says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>248)</sup> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

so you need to fix the format specifier which is incorrect and your warning will go away and you will be back in well defined behavior land.

Comment: Consider adding a brief explanation of how printf works, op clearly doesn't understand what the error is about.

Answer (score 3):

Use `%lu` instead of `%d`. `%d` is used for type `int`, `%lu` for `unsigned long`.